# ¿Como se puede usar un v-for dentro de una template en un componente?

Tags: vue.js

Ante todo gracias por tomarte el tiempo para leer mi pregunta
Estoy comenzando con vue y quería poder pasar un arreglo de cadenas en los props pero al intentar iterar las cadenas del arreglo itera pero en los caracteres del string que le paso al atributo

El javascript del componente

```
 Vue.component('navigation-main',{
      data:function (){
        return {
        
        }
      },
      props:{
        title:String,
        elements:Array
      },
      template:'<nav class="navbar"><h2>{{title}}</h2><li v-for="element in elements">{{element}}</li></nav>'
    });
```

La parte del HTML

```
<header>
      <navigation-main title='Aprendiendo Vue' elements='["Conocenos","Contactanos","BLog"]'></navigation-main>
</header>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se soluciono cambiando el atribto HTML elements por v-bind:elements

Codigo con el problema

```
<header>
      <navigation-main title='Aprendiendo Vue' elements='["Conocenos","Contactanos","BLog"]'></navigation-main>
</header>
```

Codigo solucionado

```
<header>
  <navigation-main title='Aprendiendo Vue' v-bind:elements="['Conocenos','Contactanos','BLog']"></navigation-main>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas empezando, te  invito a leer la documentación de VueJS donde esta todo lo que necesitas. [Como renderizar listas](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)

**Mapeando una matriz a elementos con** `v-for`:
Podemos usar la directiva `v-for` para representar una lista de elementos basada en una matriz. La directiva `v-for` requiere una sintaxis especial en forma de `item in items`, donde los items son la matriz de datos de origen y el `item` es un **alias** para el elemento de matriz que se está iterando:

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    {{ item.mensaje }}
  </li>
</ul>

var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { mensaje: 'Foo' },
      { mensaje: 'Bar' }
    ]
  }
})
```

El resultado de esto es:

- Foo
- Bar

Comment: No entiendo está respuesta considerando que el OP ya usa dicha directiva

Comment: Muchas gracias ya sabia lo de la directiva v-for el problema es que lo estoy intentando usar en el template del componente y no me funciona